# `page_objects_path` field doesn't work in nightwatch.config.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

I use Page Objects in nightwatch, I config the `page_objects_path` in nightwatch.conf.js, but when I reference these elements defined, got error. I don't know why.I use vue-cli to build the project.
Here's my configuration:

### `nightwatch.conf.js`

```
...
page_objects_path: 'test/e2e/pages',
...
```

The page object file `register.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {
    genderField: '.common-picker:first-child',
    genderPicker: '.picker',
    genderOptionLast: '.picker-item:last-child',
    genderPickerConfirmButton: '.picker-toolbar span:last-child',
    genderPickerCancelButton: '.picker-toolbar span:first-child'
  }
}
```

Using the page object in test files:

```
'select a gender option': function (browser) {
    browser
      .assert.hidden('@genderPicker')
      .click('@genderField')
      .pause(1000)
      .click('@genderOptionLast')
      .click('@genderPickerConfirmButton')
      .assert.containsText('@genderField', '女士')
      .pause(1000)
      .end()
  }
```

Error info:
[image: error info]

Answer (score 1):

The Page Object File should have the keyword selector for every element.

```
module.exports = {
    elements: {
        genderField: {
            selector: '.common-picker:first-child'
        },
        genderPicker: {
            selector: '.picker'
        },
        genderOptionLast: {
            selector: '.picker-item:last-child'
        },
        genderPickerConfirmButton: {
            selector: '.picker-toolbar span:last-child'
        },
        genderPickerCancelButton: {
            selector: '.picker-toolbar span:first-child'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know but what I saw in its document [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-page-objects) it says : 
`Or if you're creating elements with the same locate strategy as is default, you can use the shorthand`,which is what i used but somehow I don't know why it faild

Comment: @Jerry Did you try using `selector` keyword. If yes, can you share the error that you got.

Comment: yes, I use the `selector` keyword at last and it works , just wanna know why this shorthand wording isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your page object as a constant at the top of the test, and then call the elements from the registerPage object:

```
  'select a gender option': function (browser) {
    const registerPage = browser.page.register();
    registerPage.assert.hidden('@genderPicker')
    registerPage.click('@genderField')
    browser.pause(1000)
    registerPage.click('@genderOptionLast')
    registerPage.click('@genderPickerConfirmButton')
    registerPage.assert.containsText('@genderField', '女士')
    browser.pause(1000)
    browser.end()
  }
```

You don't need selectors in your page objects if you're using CSS for everything (which it looks like you are).

Source: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects